# How do I tell GHC that when it, with the FFI, tries to compile a C++ file, it should look for a library in a particular folder?

Tags: haskell, ffi

I've got a Haskell file, Saturn.hs, and a C++ file hssaturn.cpp and hssaturn.h, in the directory src/Galakhsy/. hssaturn.cpp needs libsaturn.cpp and/or libsaturn.hpp, which are in lib/saturn/src/lib/.

I have no idea how to compile it properly, any pointers?

Comment: Whenever somebody says "C++" and "any pointers?" in the same sentence, I feel the urge to make awful puns... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile all the C++ files to object files using `g++ -c filename.cpp`. This produces, in your case, hssaturn.o and libsaturn.o. Then compile your Haskell program with `ghc --make -o whatever Saturn.hs hssaturn.o libsaturn.o`. Also specify any shared libraries needed by the C++ stuff with `-lblabla`. You probably at least need the C++ standard library, i.e. `-lstdc++`, making the GHC command something like

```
ghc --make -o whatever Saturn.hs hssaturn.o libsaturn.o -lstdc++
```

(well, modulo the correct paths for the two object files).

Also remember to prevent name mangling by using `extern "C"` for the C++ functions you call from Haskell.

Addendum: The name libsaturn makes me think it is perhaps a library. You might want to consider compiling it as that and simply linking dynamically (with the `-l` switch to GHC as above).